# Failed to emit precompiled header for bridging header

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, objective-c-swift-bridge

I downloaded a project from GitHub, then pod the following files, some of which are written by OBJ-C and I used a bridge header.

```
pod ‘SnapKit’
pod ‘MJRefresh’
pod ‘Alamofire’
pod ‘Kingfisher’
pod ‘MBProgressHUD’
pod ‘pop’
pod ‘EVReflection’
pod ‘StreamingKit’
pod ‘iCarousel’
pod ‘ReflectionView’
```

When I run the project with Xcode 9.0 beta 2, but unfortunately the error log as follows :

> error: failed to emit precompiled header
>   '/var/folders/kd/4gh0_kxx3jx4thjb_sssmmcw0000gn/T/EvoRadio-Bridging-Header-97bd5f.pch'
>   for bridging header
>   '/Users/ringo/Downloads/EvoRadio-master/EvoRadio/Resources/EvoRadio-Bridging-Header.h'

I have googled, but no such issue.The error means it needs a PCH file?
This is my `.pch` header configuration:
[image]
It can't solve it.

How to make it?

Comment: Check out that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621448/4646572

Comment: @mrabins This is an iOS programming issue, not java

Comment: Seems like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621382/how-do-i-add-a-precompiled-header-file-to-my-ios-project/10621448#10621448. I used the wrong id... sorry.

Comment: @bkrl I use the solution you mentioned, but it didn't solve it. Pls. see the new edit with an image.

Comment: I think this thread may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/24524692/4646572

Comment: @bkrl I know it, but ' $(SRCROOT)/EvoRadio/Resources/PrefixHeader.pch' equals the attached image in the question description.They are the same.

Comment: didn't work for me either. I build fine in debug mode, get the swiftapp-swift.h error on an archive build.

Comment: I am getting same error in simulator but working fine in device. I am using Xcode 12.0.1. In Xcode 11 working on simulator also.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I also got exact same issue (Xcode9 beta 6) after I added cocoa pods for [Encrypted Core Data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data).
This is my `PodFile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'EncryptedCoreData', :git => 'https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data.git'

target 'Root' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Root

  target 'RootTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'RootUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**Solution:**
1 I added `$(inherited) non-recursive` to `Search Path -> Header Search Paths`
2 Then added `${PODS_ROOT} recursive` to `Search Path -> User Header Search Paths`
Both the above in my projects' target build settings.

Please have a look at these SO answers:
[1 Inherit Header Search Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142790/5546312)
[2 Inherit User Search Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31228319/5546312)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i have solved  it, I removed all the pods and re-pod them again.

Comment: @Ringo Make this an answer and check it as correct so others can benefit from you findings.

Comment: @D4ttatraya: Thank you so much for the answer. It saved my life. Can you please elaborate a little what exactly are those two lines doing?

Answer (score 66):

I have tried all of the above steps mentioned in the answers but nothing worked for me, the problem was basically with the deployment target version for the project and in the podfile.

In my project deployment target was 10.0 while in my podfile it was 11.0.

[image: Scr1]

[image: scr2]

Comment: this was my issue. So simple! Yet spent hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working. ‍♂️

Comment: My pod file has ios 9.0 ver. And build target was 10.0 but the issue still appeared. Changing the build target to 11.0 fixed the problem.

Comment: So simple in the end! Thanks 

Answer (score 56):

Note this can also happen **if your bridging header imports Objective-C code that itself imports your app's Swift module** via `myproject-Swift.h`. The solution is to use forward declarations for your Swift types and import the project Swift module in the `.m` file.

`@class MySwiftClass` or...

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MySwiftEnumType)`

`MySwiftEnumType` is the lowest level name even for classes. So Swift enum `MyClass.MySwiftEnumType` becomes just `MySwiftEnumType`

Comment: I'm facing with the same problem. Can you please give me more detail?

Comment: Assuming its the same problem, there is a circular reference issue, like can happen with Obj-C Headers. To fix it, in your Obj-C Header file that is referenced the swift class, remove the #import "myproject-Swift.h" (move it to the `.m` file). And create a forward declaration, `@class MySwiftClass`, for the swift class that's referenced in the ObjC class definition

Comment: @HariKaramSingh this was it! Thank you very much! Xcode should get error descriptions from stackoverflow :)

Comment: I included myclass.h in bridge file, and on myclass.h there  was -swift.h. Removing -swift.h from myclass.h import section, the problem disappeared. Thank you :)

Answer (score 32):

Make sure you're opening the proper project workspace, otherwise, the `Podfile` may not have all the resources it needs to compile.

I saw this same error on a project that had been working fine previously.

I discovered that I had accidentally opened the `ProjectName.xcodeproj` file rather than the `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file. Opened the `xcworkspace` file and presto, project was working again!

Answer (score 17):

For me, this problem occurred when I added new build configuration and scheme to the existing project.

The solution was to run `pod install` on newly created scheme. After that, project was built successfully.

Comment: In my case just running `pod install` and `pod update` did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue just when compiling for a simulator not for a hardware device. There were two compile error like:

- error: failed to emit precompiled header 'Bridging-Header-97bd5f.pch' for bridging header 'Bridging-Header.h'
- Could not find ActionSheetPicker_3_0/ActionSheetPicker.h in Bridging Header (but it was declared there)

After hours of research and try and errors it turned out, that there was no valid architecture set in the project to compile for simulators.

At `Project -> Build Settings -> User-Defined -> VALID_ARCHS` add the architecture `x86_64` to enable compilation for simulators.

Comment: I swear every other month I end up here and the winner answer is a different one. Today it was this one, thank you.

Comment: Thanks dude, saved me some time.

Comment: This led me down the right path, thank you! Turns out I had EXCLUDED_ARCHS set, and I had to go to Product > Destination > Destination Architectures and use Rosetta in order to use the Simulator. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon/

Answer (score 7):

XCode can build seccessful in the some target, but the other target can not.
Finally, I found that Header Search Paths is not the same. (Path: Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths > add item)
I copied & pasted the path from the successful target. I made it. Bravo.

[image]

Comment: Had the same situation with Xcode 12: wasn't the Search Paths though, but VALID_ARCHS flag (which became deprecated with Xcode 12, who knew https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10077), but the idea still stands - go through the build settings line by line and eventually you will find something :) 
(and perhaps clean up something in a process, that's always useful :) )

Answer (score 6):

You can try this solution. I have solved the same problem by this way.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Select "Build" on Left Menu > Find implicit dependencies

Under the build tab, check 'Find implicit dependencies':

[image: Find implicit dependencies]

Then make a clean and build again.

Comment: this option is now always checked by default.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had the same compiler error with additional errors like "Unknown type" in one of my project files, So I just added this to the problematic file, and it solved it instantly.

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: OK,maybe the issue we meet are different, so different solutions.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with this is that Xcode is unable to find header files for pods/frameworks imported in the project.

My Project experience with this: 
Updating Xcode9.2 - 9.3 where many cocoapods had to be updated due to implicit definitions now unavailable or being outdated.
I had changed the Podfile to now include 'use_frameworks!'.  Following this and after dealing with other compile issues I found the error you are experiencing.   I believe adding 'use_frameworks! was preventing some pods with support prior to iOS 8 from compiling correctly. Steps I took to correct this issue:

1. I tried deleting the Pods/ directory using cocoa `pod deintegrate`
2. I then open project with Xcode and cleaned the build folder and the project. (delete content within derived data folder)
3. I then `pod install` again but the issue persisted.
4. Ultimately I removed the use_frameworks line in Podfile and then repeated steps 1-3 and the project was now able to find the missing header files and the issue never presented it self again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case;

Under Target/Build Settings/

Product_Name section was different than **$(TARGET_NAME)**

When I changed it $(TARGET_NAME), it was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found that it was because I did not config the `Framework Search Paths` in Release Tab. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

After adding this path, it works.

Answer (score 2):

For my case I had a typo in folder name "Supporing FIles" instead of "Supporting Files".

Answer (score 2):

I also suffered from this after I updated new Xcode. After several hours of investigation, i found that if you have multiple targets, you now have to add more targets in pod file in Xcode 10. So your code should be like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'EvoRadio' do

pod ‘SnapKit’
pod ‘MJRefresh’
pod ‘Alamofire’
pod ‘Kingfisher’
pod ‘MBProgressHUD’
pod ‘pop’
pod ‘EVReflection’
pod ‘StreamingKit’
pod ‘iCarousel’
pod ‘ReflectionView’

target 'EvoRadio2ndtarget'   # add your second target

end
```

I found that in Xcode 9 you don't need to add, but in Xcode 10 you need to add this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac with a M1-Chip. [Yana Daniliuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76112352/11322034)'s answer helped me.

You have to run your app on a Rosetta architecture.
This is how you do it:

[image: Xcode Screenshot: Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Show Rosetta Destinations]

Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Select `Show Rosetta Destinations`

Then select an Emulator which has `(Rosetta)` at the end of its name.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `Podfile.lock` and re-running `pod install` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many reasons and things can do, like:

- Restart Xcode, Clean, Build
- Remove Pods directory and pod install
- Check the missing file is added to your pod file
- Check the missing file is added to you bridging header
- Change the header settings like here [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files/12142790#12142790)

The only one works for me is the accepted answer in [Xcode 9 - failed to emit precompiled header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293028/xcode-9-failed-to-emit-precompiled-header).

`platform :ios, '11.0'` in podfile **should match** the target in the project

Answer (score 0):

I had same scenario, make sure for the **file A** that you have included in **YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h**

- if it uses some other class(s), then those other classes are also included before that **File A**

Comment: Maybe we meet the cases aren't  the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was building with the wrong scheme (Top-Left menu).

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 11 I had an issue with the "Security.framework". I removed this dependency, then re added it. Ultimately fixed the other problems

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after renaming the existing Xcode project configuration in which I had another Xcode project imported.

To fix it, you have to rename the same configuration in the imported project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have been stuck in this issue for 2 working days , I would like to share my issue for you because may be future searchers are facing my problem

I was getting the mentioned error when running with command line , and I found that the command I was writing was for running `.xcodeproj` ,, but to run a `.xcworkspace` you have to write the following command

> xcodebuild -workspace PROJECTNAME.xcworkspace clean archive
>   -archivePath build/PROJECTNAME -scheme SCHEMENAME

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all was good. I had just forgotten to add '.h' in import added to the bridging header file

Was

```
import 'Test'
```

Required

```
import 'Test.h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this error in a bit different situation. Added SWIFT file in one project from another one. Checked names of bridging headers, routes - nothing helped. The reason of the error was that I did not import some of my custom classes in the bridging header. Imported - and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For M1 - check if the **Rosetta** option is on.

[image: Xcode options checkbox]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34288358)

Answer (score 0):

if the mac is M1 chip, remember choose Rosetta
PATH:
Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Show Rosetta Destinations.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone from Flutter is experiencing this issue.

please check:
Runner -> Target Runner -> Build Phases ->

inside Run Script:

This line of code should be present

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
```

[image: Image to display the code]

For some reason, when I changed schemas in xcode that got deleted or removed.