# Xcode 9 - failed to emit precompiled header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode9

I have a project in Objective-C as well as in swift by taking `MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` and i also configured the Objective-C Bridging Header. 
Also i have added 'MyprojectName-Swift.h' in .pch file.

This works fine on xcode 8.2 but when i build my project from xcode 9 i am getting the below error.

> failed to emit precompiled header
>   '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyprojectName-lajanjvhqjnfjksdsndsfkads/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyprojectName-Bridging-Header-swift_44AHJm3Z96qu-clang_2BIMGQVXGEZ09.pch'
>   for bridging header
>   '/Documents/MyProjectLocaiton/FoneApp-Bridging-Header.h'

Please help me out from this. Thanks!

Comment: Force quit the Xcode, delete the derived data, open Xcode clean your build and then run project

Comment: @GouravJoshi Thanks for the responce, I have already done all these tasks. But still have the same issue

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have not found any solution yet.

Comment: @Shubham Did you resolved the issue ?

Comment: @Maddy I got the solution of this issue, Hope this works for you too.

Comment: for me answer was 'Framework Search Paths'

Comment: How did you fix Framework Search Paths?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally i got the solution of this issue.
In my project the `Prefix Header` path is not clearly defined. Earlier the path was

> $(SRCROOT)/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch

`MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch` is in another folder inside the project folder, So i update the `Prefix Header` path to

> $(SRCROOT)/FolderName/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch

Comment: How did you do this?

Answer (score 29):

I found out that I accidentally opened the ***ProjectName.xcodeproj***
 file rather than the ***ProjectName.xcworkspace*** file.

Open the *xcworkspace* file, project will start working again!

Answer (score 24):

Read this if you using cocoapods in project.
I just update deployment target to iOS 10 or 11 in my case after updating pods and xcode make first build success. So problem was inside podfile where I had line

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

and my deployment target in project was 9.0
after I change my podfile to platform to

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

project was fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I had this issue while merging branches, my podfile was set to platform :ios, '10.3' while my xcode minimum deployment target was still at 10.0, you need to change it to 10.3 in xcode THEN run pod install

Answer (score 15):

Also make sure your import of "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" is in your .m file, and not your .h file.

Comment: I've put it on .h files, it works fine, that's not the problem

Comment: @Harris this was the workaround for me. Thank you.

Comment: You may also need to forward-declare classes and protocols in the .h file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you created a new target, but forgot to add this to your Podfile:

```
target 'Pistachio-rrzcpjs' do

end
```

Comment: The only answer worked with me..thanks man :+1:

Comment: The answer really helped me when I tried to run unit tests. The only thing I needed was to add something like:
"target :AppTests do
#some pods
end"
in podfile

Answer (score 7):

You can try this solution. I have solved the same problem by this way.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Select "Build" on Left Menu > Find implicit dependencies

Under the build tab, check 'Find implicit dependencies':

[image: Find implicit dependencies]

Then make a clean and build again.

Comment: perfect, i had disabled it to inprove build time , and then i forgot, thanks buddy

Answer (score 7):

When you are getting this error in terminal upon running the xcodebuild command, do make sure you pass -workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace

Comment: I was -project and it does not work with *.xworkspace. -workspace solved :)

Answer (score 4):

in my point of view I solved simply switch the order of import statements and build works fine.

Comment: Really it matters!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the same compiler error with additional errors like "Unknown type" in one of my project files, So I just added this to the problematic file, and it solved it instantly.

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Answer (score 3):

Adding my very own situation to the loop.

In my bridging header file, le'Ts say I added an import

`#import "File.h"`

Inside the `File.h` header file, there was a type referenced from an import that was inside the Prefix.pch, had to add the missing #import in my File.h

Comment: This happen to me too, How do you fix this things?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you must make sure your header files imported in the bridging header contains all of their dependencies (even those who were implied from the Prefix header)

Answer (score 2):

@Li Yakun
This is the solution if you have more then one target in project, every new target in podfile must have:

```
target 'NEWTARGET' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for MAINTARGET
    shared_pods
end
```

Comment: Quite unlike the other suggestions here, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have multiple targets, be aware to include your `#import`s in every file.