# Project doesn't build after last pod update

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After the last pod update, project refuses to build with the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_kAPMSafelistedEventsOptionKey", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ca9cdf99cfbae2f51d040b73dd242e94.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my current podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

project 'PROJECT'
target 'PROJECT' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', '~> 1.4'
pod 'AKNumericFormatter', '~> 0.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.10'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.13'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'LMGeocoder', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'JSONModel'
end
```

I've tried all the usual approaches to these xcode anomalies (removing derived data, restarting, updating pods, reinstalling pods, using older versions and plenty of other SO suggested fixes) and none of it helped. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: I hope you use a versioning system like Git or other. You should check what are the previously versions set when it was working by looking a the `podfile.lock`. I guess there is an update causing the issue, and so you could force the previous version.

Comment: @Larme yes but pods aren't added to git. I've tried different versions with no success

Comment: The `podfile` and `podfile.lock` should be updated in Git.

Comment: Some infos about what I resumed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575590/1801544

Comment: Share your Podfile.lock