# "failed to emit precompiled header" after downgrading Deployment target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Well This is a very common error by xcode and it has [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293028/xcode-9-failed-to-emit-precompiled-header) [many] [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779591/failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-for-bridging-header) answer on StackOverflow still I am facing this in a particular situation.

My project is running fine on iOS 11 Deployment target but when I try to downgrade my deployment target to iOS 10, it start to throw `Module map file not found` for every pod library.

**What Have I tried:**

- Updated `Podfile` `platform :ios, '10.0'`
- `pod deintegrate` then 'pod clean`and after that run`pod install`
- Clean `DerivedData` folder
- Clean project couple of times using the combination `cmd+opt+shift+k` & `cmd+shift+k`
- Check `Objective-C Bridging Header`.
- Revert back deployment target to `iOS 11` and it works on `iOS 11`
- Removing pod which showing `Module map file not found` and then it's throwing build error where I have used those library.

How can I get out from this error?

**P.S.:**
It's a mixed project of obj-c and swift 4.2.
Xcode version 11.2.1(11B53).
Cocoapods version 1.8.4

model Map file not found
[image: module map file not found]
faild to emit precompiled header
[image]

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From given set of information, it seems you are using color as an asset in your asset catalog like following screenshot

[image]

It requires min deployment target ios 11 to work. Stop using this feature if you want to run in ios 10.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using xcassets for colors. [DynamicColor](https://github.com/yannickl/DynamicColor) is a third-party pod