# Failed to emit precompiled header for bridging header with local pod frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm working for Objective-C project, that uses local pod library.
I wanted write Swift code and use it in the Objective-C project.
I did the bridging, and imported in it the bridging file the Objective-C files that I want to use with Swift.

But I faced `file not found error` for the local pod frameworks files if they used in the files imported in the  bridging file.

> :0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '....-Bridging-Header-swift_1JOPQHYEXCCEP-clang_2PPI06A9LWBDJ.pch' for bridging header '/....-Bridging-Header.h'

Local Libraries,

```
pod 'MYProjectLibCore', :path => '../MYProjectLibCore'
pod 'MYProjectLibUI', :path => '../MYProjectLibUI'
```

I tried all solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779591/failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-for-bridging-header), but it didn't help

Comment: Create an MCVE and report it on https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode click on Product near the devices and select edit scheme.
Then, under the build tab, check "Find implicit dependencies"
Clean and build the project again.