# React Native - "failed to emit precompiled header" when importing RCTViewManager.h in Xcode 15.2

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, xcode15

I'm trying to run my React Native app in Xcode 15.2 but it is giving errors stating `failed to emit precompiled header` in my bridging header file. Also it is not able to find `React/RCTBridgeModule.h` or other imports with `React/`. I'm using React Native version 0.72.5.

What is the issue & how can I resolve it?

- Upgraded deployment target to 13.0
- Tried running on Rosetta simulators & physical device
- Added React target to build
- pod deintegrate , pod install --repo-update, pod update
- Changing the header imports to "React/RCTViewManager.h", <RCTViewManager.h>, "RCTViewManager.h"
- Deleted DerivedData

[Xcode errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAMi0.png)

Comment: The issue you're facing is due to the changes in Xcode 15.2, which requires the use of the new precompiled header format. The error message you're seeing is because Xcode is unable to find the precompiled header file. check out this link you get solution or ideas. Failed to emit precompiled header for bridging header :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779591/failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-for-bridging-header

Comment: What is the new precompiled header format, can you explain here? I'm not sure to which answer you are pointing to from the mentioned thread